# Working with different URL structures

Tags: url

As I'm quite newbie to this field, I've doubts and there are some I couldn't find on Google, i.e:

If I'm not wrong, *index.html* makes it possible to avoid to add the filename to the url, **www.example.com/** is equal to **www.example.com/index.html**.
And that works for the following subdirectories, right?
**www.example.com/music/**

- Is there any other way to achieve this without using an index.html file? (I've read smth about converting dynamic urls to static: **./?var1=value1&varN=valueN** -> **./value1/valueN**)
- How can I convert **www.example.com/music/** to **music.example.com/** and why should it be used?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For the "should" part of the question, there are many [previous threads](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=should+sub-domains) already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define which file acts as the entry page. On an Apache server, you do this with a file named `.htaccess` which you place in the root directory (or in a specific directory). This file is a normal text file, with following line you define an entry page:

```
DirectoryIndex hello.html
```

Now, if anybody calls your directory `http://www.example.com`, the page `http://www.example.com/hello.html` will actually be shown.

The filename `index.html` is just a convention. If no entry page is defined, the server tries a few default filenames like `index.html`, `index.php`, etc.